# Torquebox setup on Ubuntu MaxPermSize

Tags: java, linux, jboss, torquebox

I've got a little problem while installing torquebox on a Ubuntu 16.04 Server.
The installation it self was easy, but now, when I wan to start the torquebox server with "torquebox run" I'm getting the error:

> [WARNING] root-knob.yml has not been deployed. Starting TorqueBox
>   anyway. Booting AS7 from configuration
>   /opt/torquebox-current/jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
>   /opt/torquebox-current/jboss/bin/standalone.sh
>   -Djruby.home=/opt/torquebox-3.2.0/jruby --server-config=standalone.xml JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with
>   values: -Xms64m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
>
> JBoss Bootstrap Environment
>
> JBOSS_HOME: /opt/torquebox-current/jboss
>
> JAVA: java
>
> JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx768m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
>
> Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m' Error: Could not create the
>   Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program
>   will exit. root@h2657400:~#

So I have no idea what to do now. Installed is torquebox 3.2 and Java Version 9-Internal (preinstalled on server).
Does anyone has had the same problem and knows how to solve it? I would appreciate that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `MaxPermSize` is no longer a legal option for Java 9, so that's triggering your error. You could modify `/opt/torquebox-current/jboss/bin/standalone.sh` to remove the `MaxPermSize` option, but I suspect you will then run in to other problems due to incompatibilities between TorqueBox itself and Java 9. I recommend switching back to Java 8 if possible.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful, I've installed Java 7 and this works (or let's say, it's not working on an other point)